# How can I use my own icons in dijit.menuItems?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following code:

```
require(['dojo/dom', 'dijit/Menu', 'dijit/MenuItem', 'dijit/CheckedMenuItem', 'dijit/MenuSeparator', 'dijit/PopupMenuItem', 'dojo/on'],
    function(dom, menu, menuItem, checkedMenuItem, menuSeparator, popupMenuItem, on)
    {
        var pMenu= new menu({
            targetNodeIds: ['moreOptionsImage1', 'moreOptionsImage2'],
            leftClickToOpen: true
        });


        pMenu.addChild(new menuItem({
            label : "See Description",
            iconSrc: "description.png"
        }));

        pMenu.startup();


    });
```

But the file description.png is not showing in the menu. Am I doing something obviously very wrong?

**EDIT:** I figured that there is something called image class in CSS and images can be inserted using it. But is there any other way to do it? Without using image class perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `iconSrc` parameter in Dijits that support icons. The default Dijit way of specifying a custom icon is to use the `iconClass` parameter when initializing your Dijit:

```
pMenu.addChild(new menuItem({
    label : "See Description",
    iconClass: "myCustomIcon"
}));
```

You'll need to add a rule for the `myCustomIcon` class in your stylesheet:

```
.myCustomIcon {
    background-image: url('myCustomIcon.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

That's it, nothing more. If you want to add multiple custom icons you could look into creating an imagesprite for them, a good read on that, "Themes and theming" can be found in the reference guide:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/themes.html#icons